# Parse an XML feed with PHP SimpleXML and display only one result at a time with a 30 second delay in between results.

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

The data comes from a XML feed that I need to parse using SimpleXML.

I want to display only one entry result at a time with a 30 second delay in between results.

Display example would be:

Title: 1

Id: 1

Then 30 seconds later

Title: 2

Id: 2

And so on.

Here is my code example:

```
$str = <<<XML
<feed>
    <entry>
        <title>Title 1</title>
        <id>1</id>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>Title 2</title>
        <id>2</id>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>Title 3</title>
        <id>3</id>
    </entry>
</feed>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);

foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {
    echo "Title: ".$entry->title."<br/>";
    echo "Id: ".$entry->id."<br/>";
}
```

Right now this code outputs everything in the XML file:

Title: 1

Id: 1

Title: 2

Id: 2

Title: 3

Id: 3

How can I display the first entry for 30 seconds then have the second entry display in place of the first entry.  This would continue until the end of the XML file and then start over again.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: By using a timer in jquery and use ajax to get the information you need?

Comment: It's important to understand the relationship between PHP on the server, and the behaviour of the browser. The PHP code is not directly controlling what is on the screen and when; the browser sends a request, and the PHP code generates a response; and that's the end. To control the browser - add delays, refresh the screen, etc - you need to be running code *in the browser*, usually JavaScript. (There are a few tricks outside of that, but not that are worth considering most of the time.)